# Application is taking more time to process the JNI weak reference during remark phase of G1GC

Tags: garbage-collection, java-native-interface, java-7, g1gc

The application is running to unexpected behavior due to this long GC and am trying to bring the GC time below 500ms.

Snippet from GC logs:

```
2020-03-17T16:50:04.505+0900: 1233.742: [GC remark 
2020-03-17T16:50:04.539+0900: 1233.776: [GC ref-proc
2020-03-17T16:50:04.539+0900: 1233.776: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0096740 secs]
2020-03-17T16:50:04.549+0900: 1233.786: [WeakReference, 3643 refs, 0.0743530 secs]
2020-03-17T16:50:04.623+0900: 1233.860: [FinalReference, 89 refs, 0.0100470 secs]
2020-03-17T16:50:04.633+0900: 1233.870: [PhantomReference, 194 refs, 9 refs, 0.0168580 secs]
2020-03-17T16:50:04.650+0900: 1233.887: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.9726330 secs], 1.0839410 secs], 1.1263670 secs]
```

Application is running on Java 7 with the below JVM options:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:GCLogFileSize=52428800 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=4294967296 
-XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=8589934592 -XX:MaxPermSize=805306368 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:NewRatio=5 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=30 -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:PermSize=268435456 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+UseStringCache
```

Changing the parameters like NewRatio, MaxTenuringThreshold, InitialHeapSize etc is changing the frequency of such long GCs, but still there are one or two.

Is there any way to figure out what is contributing to long processing time of JNI weak reference?

Comment: I have never done JNI and weak references l, but it seems that you use a library that does that. You need to find out which one is it

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: sorry I dont, is upgrade an option may be? You use java7 and I assume CMS collector

Comment: Tried to use CMS collector, but it didn't work as Full GC was happening towards the end. More over I am looking forward to figure out why JNI is taking more time in Remark phase and fix that.